# Magento Layered Nav - Checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, magento

Does anybody know a way to turn the layered nav into checkboxes? Bit like asos...

I see there are modules for sale saying they does this, possibly going to go down that route, but just seeing if there is an alternative.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to basically what the other paid modules are doing, and just program it yourself.  Magento does not give you the option to have checkboxes, they just didn't program in a way to do that.

Magento does though allow multiple options in the url query string if you manually put it in.  Let's say you have a "Color" filter.  One of the options is Red (option id = 35) and Blue (option id = 38).  In the query string, you can put ...?color=35&color=38 and it will show the results for both colors.

That said, you would have to override the functionality Magento uses to spit out the filers, and make it so that checkboxes work to select, but instead of showing up in the "Currently Shopping By" section, you'd want them all to stay visible, but only be checked if you've selected that option.

So, you can either pay the money for a module and not spend any time doing it yourself, or not buy one and build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much - Whic would you recomend purchasing? Think it'll probably be best to go down that route...

Comment: @Prattski if i put an attribute like solution=12&solution=1 in url, it takes only last value. i.e solution=1

Comment: param return only like Array ( [id] => 3 [solution] => 1 )